# Using the latest <windns.h> from C++Builder11

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio, c++builder-11-alexandria

I'm trying to use the `DnsServiceRegister` function (available in `<windns.h>` per  [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsserviceregister) ) from a C++Builder app, compiled with C++Builder 11.3.

The `<windns.h>` header that BCB ships with does not have the function included and the compilation fails.
Is there any way to use the newer header and the `.lib` files that are provided by my external win sdk installation?

Comment: You can't use `.lib` files from another SDK.  `.lib` files are compiler-specific, and the Windows SDK is intended for Visual Studio, that's why C++Builder has to ship with its own `.lib` files. In this situation, I would suggest simply defining the function in your own code and then use `GetProcAddress()` to access it at runtime.